# Pass boolean value in a curl request

Tags: json, bash, curl

My goal is to have an attribute `isAdmin` in my `users` schema that is a boolean value, defaulted to false, and can be sent a true value in a CURL request.

I started off with this in my schema:

```
isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
    required: true
  }
```

and have a working CURL request and the isAdmin returns false as expected.

```
API="http://localhost:4741"
URL_PATH="/sign-up"
EMAIL="a2@admin.com"
PASSWORD="test"


curl "${API}${URL_PATH}" \
  --include \
  --request POST \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{
    "credentials": {
      "email": "'"${EMAIL}"'",
      "password": "'"${PASSWORD}"'",
      "password_confirmation": "'"${PASSWORD}"'"
    }
  }'
```

I then tried to take the default value out:

```
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  }
```

..and try passing T or F in the CURL request and it's not working. The error says that `isAdmin` is required. Not sure what is wrong with my CURL request.

```
API="http://localhost:4741"
URL_PATH="/sign-up"
EMAIL="a2@admin.com"
PASSWORD="test"
ADMIN="True"

curl "${API}${URL_PATH}" \
  --include \
  --request POST \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{
    "credentials": {
      "email": "'"${EMAIL}"'",
      "isAdmin": "'"${ADMIN}"'",
      "password": "'"${PASSWORD}"'",
      "password_confirmation": "'"${PASSWORD}"'"
    }
  }'
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? And/Or how I can have a default value of false and POST a new user with a true `isAdmin` attribute? Thank you in advance for any advice.

Clarification: Using Mongoose and ExpressAPI.

Comment: What is this? A bash script?

Comment: @NeilLunn yes a shell script

Comment: I presume the server will parse the JSON. So if you just typed the JavaScript object through your favorite JSON parser ( hint open the browser console and use `JSON.stringify` ) then what does the string output look like? And then of course make your string look exactly the same as that.

Comment: Might I suggest using one of the command line JSON tools to generate proper JSON?  All it takes is for someone to stick a quote mark in an e-mail address or password and your script is broken.

Comment: Per RFC 8259, A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of the following three literal names: `false null true`. **The literal names MUST be lowercase.** No other literal names are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are enclosing the value in double quotes, it seems to be treated as a string, rather than boolean.  Try this:

```
ADMIN=true # may be it is safer to use all lowercase for true/false
curl "${API}${URL_PATH}" \
  --include \
  --request POST \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{
    "credentials": {
      "email": "'"${EMAIL}"'",
      "isAdmin": '${ADMIN}',
      "password": "'"${PASSWORD}"'",
      "password_confirmation": "'"${PASSWORD}"'"
    }
  }'
```

Comment: Did this solve the issue?  Were you able to resolve your problem otherwise?